# Efficient pixel by pixel grayscale measurement in numpy and tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a mix of 3 channel grayscale and color images in a directory, and I'd like to make a measure in numpy for how much an RGB image is actually empirically grayscale and for this to be very efficiently computed.

I understand that if R==G==B, I have a grayscale pixel, and if R,G,B per pixel are not equal, I have a colored pixel.  I'm OK with saying the grayscaliness is what fraction of pixels are grayscale vs colored.  All true grayscale images should have a score == 1.

I've made a silly metric that works in PIL:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open(filename)
>>> sum([1 for pixel in im.getdata() if (pixel[0]==pixel[1]==pixel[2])])/len(list(im.getdata()))
```

For an arbitrary im == color:

```
0.0003056384175265294
```

For an im == Grayscale:

```
1.0
```

So this works as expected.

What's the right way to broadcast this correctly assuming I'm starting with a numpy array or a tensorflow tensor rather than a file I can access raw pixels in PIL?

I'm starting with:

```
sess = tf.Session()

dat = tf.read_file(filename)
ten = tf.image.decode_jpeg(dat)
x = sess.run(ten)

>>> x[0,0,:]
array([255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Looks good.  I tried the following, which doesn't seem to produce what I was looking for:

```
def grayscaler(x):
  """Input is a pixel.  Compare R == G == B"""
  if (x[0] == x[1] == x[2]):
    return 1
  else:
    return 0

>>> np.mean(np.apply_along_axis(grayscaler , axis=2, arr=x))
```

Unfortunately, no matter the image, color or grayscale, I always get 1, color or grayscale, so my function above doesn't translate correctly.

```
>>> np.mean(np.apply_along_axis(grayscaler, axis=2, arr=x))
1.0
```

What's the right syntax and function for looping over all 3 color channels in a pixel-by-pixel manner for a numpy array?

Answer (score 2):

Think big, think in terms of tensors. A simple idea would be
1. compute the gray-scale version (poor-man way)
2. subtract gray-scale version from intput
3. L2-distance

What about

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

fake_color = np.random.randn(8, 256, 256, 3).astype(np.float32)
fake_grayscale = np.random.randn(8, 256, 256, 3).mean(axis=3, keepdims=True).astype(np.float32)


def measure_grayscale(x):
    gray_version = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=3, keepdims=True)
    difference = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(x, gray_version), axis=[1, 2, 3])
    return difference


def regions_grayscale(x, tresh=0.1):
    gray_version = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=3, keepdims=True)
    difference = tf.squared_difference(x, gray_version)
    return tf.greater(difference, tresh * tf.ones_like(difference))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    print sess.run(measure_grayscale(data), {data: fake_color})
    print sess.run(measure_grayscale(data), {data: fake_grayscale})
```

This gives here:

- [0.6701656  0.6660412  0.6667728  0.6642832  0.667957   0.66799116
  0.6700557  0.66249603] for the batch of color images
- [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] for the batch of only grayscale images

Detecting regions which are grayscale according to your heuristic can be done via thresholding in `regions_grayscale`. You can even apply `tf.reduce_mean(.., axis=1)` to get your "silly metric" to work.

The syntax to NumPy is the same. As you use the tag of TensorFlow the code above is using TensorFlow.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your fake_grayscale is pushed into 1 channel, right?
```>>> fake_grayscale = np.random.randn(8, 256, 256, 3).mean(axis=3, keepdims=True).astype(np.float32)
>>> y = fake_grayscale[0]
>>> y.shape
(256, 256, 1)
```

Comment: I'm also trying to fill in your `tf.reduce_mean(.., axis=1)` with
`      is_grayscale = tf.reduce_mean(tf.map_fn(grayscaler,
                                              my_images), axis=1)`
Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: It is not pushed into one channel. It keeps all 3 channels b but having the same values. The 'is_grayscale' can be done similar with 'tf.greater'